# Different output from mariadb query and using postman

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb, postman

Hello I have a query to return a JSON value from the database to backend. When I query it directly from the database (phpmyadmin) it works fine and the query return correct value. But when I access it using postman, it returns different value (it returns null)

This the result from the query from phpmyadmin

```
{
"name": "Desi Ratnaningsih", 
"day": "Monday", 
"schedule": 
    [
        {"start": "10:00:00", "end": "13:00:00"},
        {"start": "17:00:00", "end": "20:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

This is the result from postman

```
{
    "name": "Desi Ratnaningsih",
    "day": "Monday",
    "schedule": null
}
```

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT( 
'name', d.name, 
'day', s.day, 
'schedule', JSON_EXTRACT(( 
           SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT( JSON_OBJECT( 'start', h.start, 'end', h.end )) ,']') 
           FROM hours h JOIN schedules s ON h.id = s.working_hour 
           JOIN doctors d ON s.doctor_id = d.doctor_id WHERE d.doctor_id =1 AND s.day="Monday"),'$') ) AS data 
FROM doctors d JOIN schedules s ON d.doctor_id=s.doctor_id 
JOIN hours h on s.working_hour = h.id 
WHERE d.doctor_id = 1 AND s.day="Monday";
```

Comment: It loks like you should be using `GROUP BY d.docker_id` rather than `DISTINCT`, [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/) should be used instead of `GROUP_CONCAT` and with that you should be able to get down to a single query (without sub queries). Why postman is different might be a stricter SQL mode, but fix the query and both should be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this simpler/correct?

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 
'name', d.name, 
'day', s.day, 
'schedule', JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT( 'start', h.start, 'end', h.end )) 
) AS data 
FROM doctors d
JOIN schedules s ON d.doctor_id=s.doctor_id 
JOIN hours h on s.working_hour = h.id 
WHERE d.doctor_id = 1 AND s.day="Monday"
GROUP BY d.docker_id, s.day;
```

This required MariaDB-10.5.

For earlier versions the `GROUP_CONCAT` approach would be:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 
'name', d.name, 
'day', s.day, 
'schedule', CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT( JSON_OBJECT( 'start', h.start, 'end', h.end ) ) ,']') 
) AS data 
FROM doctors d
JOIN schedules s ON d.doctor_id=s.doctor_id 
JOIN hours h on s.working_hour = h.id 
WHERE d.doctor_id = 1 AND s.day="Monday"
GROUP BY d.docker_id, s.day;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like MariaDB does not support JSON_ARRAYAGG function

Comment: It does from 10.5.0 onward.